# How do I unset a unique field from all documents in Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose/nodeJS and I'm writing some migration scripts using `node-migrate`.

My update script is adding a new computed field to all documents in a collection:

```
exports.up = function (done) {
  Posts.find({_hash: null}, function (err, posts) {
    async.forEach(posts, function (post, next) {
      var hash = hash(post);
      post.update({_hash: hash}, next);
    }, done);
  });
};
```

and that works fine. I'm grabbing all docs with no `hash` field, computing it, and updating the record.

But `node-migrate` supports "downward" migrations as well, to rollback changes. In this case I want to *remove* the hash field from all docs that have one.

```
exports.down = function (done) {
  Posts.update({_hash: {$ne: null}}, {$unset: {$hash: 1}}, {multi: true}, done);
};
```

but i get a duplicate key error. The schema does indeed define that field as uniquely indexed, so that makes sense..?

How can I unset/delete a field from all docs in a collection if that field is defined as unique?

Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed the dup key error looks a little suspect: `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: myApp.posts.$_hash_1  dup key: { : null }`..? Why does it say `dup key: { : null }`, that looks like an object literal without a key and just a null value. Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code sample. The first argument of `Posts.udpate` is missing a closing `}`: `{_hash: {$ne: null}`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLavers, just a typo in the SO post; unrelated. Fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

A unique index will not allow multiple docs where the indexed field is either missing or `null`.

To support this, you will need to drop the existing unique index on `hash` and re-create it as a unique, [sparse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) index.

Drop the index in the shell:

```
db.posts.dropIndex('$_hash_1')
```

Update the definition of `hash` in your schema to make it a sparse, unique index:

```
hash: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}}
```